# How to set a static set of x-axis values and legend for a Plotly Bar Graph?

Tags: python, data-science, bar-chart, plotly-dash, plotly-python

The Plotly Bar graphs below show a count of employees in three different seniority classes for a given dept (engineering, accounting, etc..)

If one of the many values for the x-axis is not in the current data frame used to construct the graph, no bar/x-axis/color is shown. Below accounting has employees in all three so they show but accounting doesn't possess all there.

Is there something I can do to make sure this graph consistently shows all three values and that a missing x-axis value will assume a default y-axis value of 0.

I want the engineering graph to show an bar for sr as well but default the value to 0.

[Ploty Graph showing Count by Seniority (Junior, Mid, Senior) for Engineering Dept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOrDl.png)

[Ploty Graph showing Count by Seniority (Junior, Mid, Senior) for Accounting Dept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqeN9.png)

Here is a snippet of the code use to generate the graph above as well as snapshot of the master Dataframe.

```
fig = px.bar(g[g['dept']=='accounting']
         , x='level', y='id', color='level', labels = {
             'level' : 'Job Seniority',
             'id' : 'Employee Count'
         }, title='Count by Seniority (Junior, Mid, Senior) for Accounting Dept')
```

In code snippet above, g points to a Dataframe that looks like this:

|  | dept | level | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | accounting | jr | 1 |
| 1 | accounting | mid | 2 |
| 2 | accounting | sr | 1 |
| 3 | business development | jr | 2 |
| 4 | business development | mid | 1 |
| 5 | business development | sr | 1 |
| 6 | engineering | jr | 2 |
| 7 | engineering | mid | 1 |
| 8 | human resources | jr | 1 |
| 9 | legal | jr | 1 |
| 10 | legal | mid | 1 |
| 11 | legal | sr | 1 |
| 12 | marketing | jr | 2 |
| 13 | marketing | mid | 1 |
| 14 | research and development | jr | 1 |
| 15 | sales | sr | 1 |
| 16 | services | jr | 2 |
| 17 | services | mid | 1 |
| 18 | support | jr | 3 |
| 19 | support | mid | 2 |
| 20 | training | mid | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

- prepare the data for plotting by organising index and columns
- used **graph_objects** so `make_subplots()` can be used so it's a simple looping process to generate a graph per department (not **plotly** is 1-indexed, python 0-indexed)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


df = pd.DataFrame({"dept": ["accounting", "accounting", "accounting", "business development", "business development", "business development", "engineering", "engineering", "human resources", "legal", "legal", "legal", "marketing", "marketing", "research and development", "sales", "services", "services", "support", "support", "training"], 
 "level": ["jr", "mid", "sr", "jr", "mid", "sr", "jr", "mid", "jr", "jr", "mid", "sr", "jr", "mid", "jr", "sr", "jr", "mid", "jr", "mid", "mid"], 
 "id": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2]})

dfp = df.groupby(["dept","level"]).sum().unstack("level").fillna(0).droplevel(0,1).T

fig = make_subplots(rows=(len(dfp.columns)+1)//3, cols=3, subplot_titles=dfp.columns)
for i, c in enumerate(dfp.columns):
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=dfp.index, y=dfp[c], showlegend=False, 
                         marker_color=np.select([dfp.index=="jr",dfp.index=="mid"],["red","blue"],"green")), 
                  row=(i//3)+1, col=(i%3)+1)
    
fig.update_layout({"margin":{"b":0,"t":20,"l":0,"r":0}})
```

[image]